# How to fix the psycopg2 syntax error at or near '%' -> VALUES (%s, %s, %s...?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am trying to insert in a table using below query,
some of the records getting inserted and below code is used to implement:

```
query = '''INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s);'''
cursor.execute(query, (val1, val2,))
```

I am inserting records of table A into the another table B, Total number of records in A are 51, but 45 successfully inserted and 6 of them failed.
FYI, when i explicitly inserted the failed 6 records into B, they got successfully inserted.

Can please someone help me here? Where is the problem in the code, that some records are failing and when i explicitly insert them they doesn't fail.

The error printed is below:
Error : "syntax error at or near "%""

Comment: Where is `VALUES (%s, %s, %s...)` coming from? It does not match your query string. What are the values for `val1, val2`?

Comment: Please don't post code and error message in the same quote block.  Which is which?

Comment: @jjanes the code/error formatting was me. That is why I asked about `VALUES (%s, %s, %s...)`, trying to figure what we are looking at?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver code is below: query = '''INSERT INTO ws_engr_ecps.tmp_scg_device (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s);'''
cursor.execute(query, (val1, val2,))

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i have updated the question, please comment now

Comment: @jjanes i have updated the question, please comment now

Comment: You still have not shown us what the data values being passed to `val1, val2` are, in particular the ones that failed. Nor have you shown how you are iterating over the data set to get to the INSERT query.

Comment: I should have been clearer, the form of your code is correct. The issue, I'm pretty sure, is the data being passed in. At a guess improper escaping.